# reference a property on a custom attribute

Tags: javascript, aurelia

How does one deal with situation where I have a custom attribute, lets say it is a pager, where I have properties totalItems,currentPage, and itemsPerPage among others. There is a computed property called numberOfPages as well. How do you "share" this property numberOfPages outside of custom attribute. In angular, you would set it on the $scope. How does one do it in aurelia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use attribute-name.ref

```
<div pager="..." pager.ref="pager">
  <span>${pager.numberOfPages} pages</span>
</div>
```

> #### ref
>
> Creates a reference to an HTML element, a component or a component's parts.
>
> - `ref="someIdentifier"` or `element.ref="someIdentifier"` - Create a reference to the HTMLElement in the DOM.
> - `attribute-name.ref="someIdentifier"`- Create a reference to a custom attribute's view-model.
> - `view-model.ref="someIdentifier"`- Create a reference to a custom element's view-model.
> - `view.ref="someIdentifier"`- Create a reference to a custom element's view instance (not an HTML Element).
> - `controller.ref="someIdentifier"`- Create a reference to a custom element's controller instance.
>
> -- [aurelia docs](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/5)

Working Gist here:
https://gist.run/?id=0b60a1687e213797a8adc0d5ca870c06

**Edit:**
If you're actually building a pager, consider creating a custom element with a template part. You'll have a much easier time.

Comment: ups if you liked it, checks if you loved it, see you next question

Comment: only problem I see with this solution is it doesn't really set up binding so there's no way to be notified of changes to the value of `pager.numberOfPages` in the parent VM.

Comment: That wasn't the question though. To that end, I'd say view models almost never need to be notified of changes to properties of other view models. View model properties are state properties, and setting up a custom attribute like this serves the purpose of abstracting away a specific subset of functionality behind an API. If you wanted to be notified to update the view, for example, you should do what I've done above and just use it in the template. The templating engine knows how to observe it.

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis yes, I am trying to port angular bootstrap ui implementation of pagination as custom attribute to aurelia. I want to see if I can replicated functionality as it is in angular.